# IOS UI popoverController doesn't dismiss by tapping outside after device orientation changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipopovercontroller, device-orientation

I am facing a weird issue with `UIPopoverController`. While creating the popover, we have set passthrough views property. We wanted to popover to close if we tap anywhere outside it.

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItemView
              permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
              animated:YES];
// comment the below line if only toggle feature is expected to close the popover
[self.popover setPassthroughViews:self.tileMenu.tileMenuButtonsArray];
```

It works fine untill device's orientation changes. after orientation change, tapping outside has no effect. The method `- popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover` - is never called after orientation changes. If I tap on the button again, then it starts working fine. i.e. it relaunches the popover and closes the popover if i tap outside.

I am working on IOS 7 now.

Has anyone faced this issue before? any help will be appreciated.

Update:
I tried dismissing and reopening the popover. It didn't work as well:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if ( [self.popover isPopoverVisible] )
    {
        [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
        self.reopenPopover = YES;
    }
}

-(void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation        
{

    if (self.reopenPopover) {
    [self presentPopover:self.selectedTileMenuBarButtonItem];
    }
    self.reopenPopover = NO;
}

-(void) presentPopover:(UIBarButtonItem *) barButtonItemView {
    self.selectedTileMenuBarButtonItem = barButtonItemView;

    [self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItemView
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                     animated:YES];
    // comment the below line if only toggle feature is expected to close the popover
    [self.popover setPassthroughViews:self.tileMenu.tileMenuButtonsArray];
}
```

Comment: have you used contentSizeForViewInPopover anywhere ?

Comment: yes... it is used inside the views we load inside the popover

Comment: then use preferredContentSize instead of that because it is depricated in IOS 7

Comment: dismiss popover while rotation and again make it visible ..This will work...

Comment: This is a hack and might work. I am trying it right now. but is there a proper way to handle it?

Comment: That didn't worked either

Comment: Can you tell me how you are implementing dat?

Comment: there was an issue with my implementation. we had UIButtons and no UIBarButtonItem. We were doing `UIButton *control = (UIButton *) sender;
 UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItemView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
 [barButtonItemView setCustomView:control];` because of an earlier issue we were facing with orientation change. And then using it for popover using the above mentioned way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the implementation which I have fixed now and it worked. 
We had UIButtons and not UIBarButton but due to some earlier issue with method `presentPopoverFromRect`(there were issues when orientation of the ipad changes), we were presenting the popovers this way:

```
UIButton *control = (UIButton *) sender;
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItemView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];        
[barButtonItemView setCustomView:control]; 
[self.popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:barButtonItemView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
```

it wasn't required. the below code fixed the issue:

```
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:[sender bounds] inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

// comment the below line if only toggle feature is expected to close the popover
[self.popover setPassthroughViews:self.tileMenu.tileMenuButtonsArray];
```